# If I have encrypt and decrypt function for password, is there any way that we can not print the decrypted password in our java code?

Tags: java, encryption, password-encryption

I have a function encrypt and decrypt for encryption and decryption of password. When i send my password to database i encrypt it and send but to use it i decrpt it first and send it there.
 But i dont want anyone to use **System.out.println** to print the password on console. 
It should be locked in some way.
What can we do for that? I have already coded in java and written my code using Key.
My code is

```
String text = "Hello World";
String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
 // Create key and cipher
 Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 // encrypt the text
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
 byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
 System.err.println(new String(encrypted));
// decrypt the text
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey); String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
System.err.println(decrypted);
```

Comment: 1st thing dont use String for password. Use char[].

Comment: Encryption and Decryption on passwords in never a safe option. You should hash functions instead.

Comment: @RamanSahasi Nice idea but that only works if you use the password to *verify* what the user entered. If you use the password to authenticate to another service, you need to be able to reconstruct it to its original.

Comment: Do you need the password only for user authentication, or do you need to send the plaintext password to another service?

Comment: i have a common.properties file there we write db details. I dont want anyone to see my db password so written in encrypted form there. but while we decrypt anyone who has the code can know the password.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution to your issue.

Never encrypt/decrypt a password, it is a possible security breach.
Use a hash function for password hashing to a string, those hashes usually stored in databases, and password authentication usually done by comparing hashed passwords with those in the database.

Thus making it impossible for anyone except a valid password holder to know the true password.